Obtener información y link publico de reels de instagram usando la API
Estoy desarrollando un chat en donde se puede enviar y recibir mensajes de la plataforma de instagram, pero tengo un problema y es que cuando recibo un reel me llega la siguiente información:
 {
     "object": "instagram",
     "entry": [
       {
         "time": 1732591959811,
         "id": "unshow_id",
         "messaging": [
           {
             "sender": {
               "id": "unshow_id"
             },
             "recipient": {
               "id": "unshow_id"
             },
             "timestamp": 1732591959335,
             "message": {
               "mid": "unshow_id",
               "attachments": [
                 {
                   "type": "ig_reel",
                   "payload": {
                     "reel_video_id": "18044757400832527",
                     "title": "En minutos tenés un delicioso tostado \n\nETIQUETA PARA QUE TE LO PREPAREN \n\n#pan #panrapido #recetasfáciles #delicious #delicioso #queso #jamon #cheese #homemade #yummy",
                     "url": "https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/ig_messaging_cdn/?asset_id=18044757400832527&signature=Abw0PAmoBEhpdlqAKvozRHcJjiTslJBeiFGcBzkeL1NIvpn3ctp70ycUK2tTmCx5EzUpMApgzMNgB0pQCZR0x06hDUhUmSRx7EAqRLsOR0gRz9GwRLJnz6AT2ycMExq1_IFOXn0FWd2jHYWpgnN9Ab671ZdJMB2fqgTm191VQTgGkV1g3PuK4vazPxLhTwB2l3IHp6uzo9J7GINje5lYfM6BIQCDAUI"
                   }
                 }
               ]
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }

La pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo recuperar la URL publica del reel?
Probé de muchas maneras pero no he podido darle al blanco

Que lenguaje estás utilizando para manejar los datos que te retorna el API ( JavaScript, C#, PHP, ... )
